# Shapely : cascaded_union seems to return too many polygons

Tags: polygon, shapely, union, python-3

I'm trying to get the union of around 4,000 polygons using Shapely's cascaded_union function. The output of this function is a multipolygon in my case, which is normal since many input polygons do not overlap.

Yet, when I draw the output, I can clearly see that some small polygons are included whereas these polygons belong to a larger polygon. To my mind, these small polygons should be excluded from the union.

Here is a sample screenshot with 3 polygons of the union returned by shapely. The blue one is the bigger one with 43 185 exterior points and the green and orange ones are the smaller ones.

[image: union of polygons]

I also uploaded a text file containing the coordinates of the 3 Polygons using the built-in function mapping() from the shapely.geometry module.

It can be accessed [there](https://uploadfiles.io/t3lxj).

The file contains a dictionary {index:{...}} with 3 indexes, each of them containing a dictionnary representing a Polygon. If you need to get back the coordinates from the file, you can use the following Python code:

```
with open("file_polygon.txt","r") as f:
    testl = f.readlines()
teststr = "".join(testl)
testd = json.loads(teststr)
for index in testd:
    # List of exterior points of the polygon of index "index"
    ps = testd[index]["coordinates"][0]
```

If you have any clue of why these polygons are returned by the cascaded_union function, I would be happy to get them :).

Comment: Your link leads to nothing